# Function '.test' in JavaScript. Testing for a variable

Tags: javascript, regex, testing

I am having issues searching for a variable within a variable. The code that I have is:

```
var str = "13, 12, 12, 12";

//Look for string = 13 in str.
var string = 13;

var patt = "/" + string + "/g";
var result = patt.test(str);
```

What is my error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
var patt = new RegExp(string, 'g');
```

to build your pattern. The `/something/g` construct cannot be used for dynamic patterns.

See [MDN's documentation on regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use `indexOf` function as below:

```
var str="13, 12, 12, 12";
var string= "13";
var result = str.indexOf(string)>=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get `indexOf` the first value of 13 in `str`, I would do following:

```
var str = "13, 12, 12, 12";
var string = "13";
var result = str.match(/\d{1,}/g).indexOf(string); //returns 0
```

This will match only if `str` has the value 13. For example, 131 would not match like in your current code. If you are trying to test if the value 13 exists in `str`, I would do following:

```
var str = "13, 12, 12, 12";
var string = "13";
var result = (str.match(/\d{1,}/g).indexOf(string) !== -1); //Returns true
```